# Can't connect to Spring Boot or to Mysql when using a VPN

Tags: mysql, spring, angular, spring-boot, vpn

I work on Spring Boot and Angular4 which are deploy on a local server in my company. All works well when we connect directly from the local network, but when I use a VPN, the Angular4 app looks not able to connect to Spring Boot, or it's perhaps the Spring Boot app which is not able to connect to database.

Here is how spring boot is connected to database:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table_name?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Here is my constant used to connect Angular4 with Spring Boot:

```
export const appConfig = {
    apiUrl: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8081',
};
```

Here is a screen shot of the error:
[image]

Thanks for help

Comment: Not really spring specific. This is a network issue. First determine which part is not connecting. Is it the rest call from angular to your spring boot, or is it the connection to the db?

also which parts of the app is sitting behind the vpn? both the spring boot app and the db? or just the db?

Comment: I think it's a spring boot or mysql issue because I have a meteor application on the same ip and it works. Both spring boot and db are behind the vpn. I can't find any error on error files, so I don't know which connection failed...